# Repeated measures results and model singular

Tags: r, repeated-measures

I have visited the posts about this problem but I don't manage to solve mine. I am trying to do an anova repeated measures but always get the message "Model is singular" and I don't know how to deal with the results.

My data are:
"Eggs" is the VD
"Population" is a between-subject VI with 3 levels
"Week" is a within-subject VI with 2 levels.

I collected individuals from different populations and I counted how many eggs laid every female along 2 weeks.

I have tried:

```
aov(Eggs ~ Population * Week + Error(Female/Week), data = dfCPost_tF)
```

and despite the warning "model is singular" I got the following results:

```
Error: Female
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Population                2   9200    4600  12.710  2e-05 ***
Week             1   1451    1451   4.010 0.0492 *  
Population:Week  1    112     112   0.308 0.5806    
Residuals         69  24971     362                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Female:Week
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Week               1    316   315.7   2.044 0.1575  
Population:Week    2   1272   636.2   4.120 0.0206 *
Residuals         66  10191   154.4                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Within
          Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  1 3.71e-30 3.71e-30
```

I didn't expected to find Week in the first table, and then I am not sure what p is the right one for Week and for Population:week. If someone can explain me were can be the problem delaing with singular model I would appreciate it.